# Uploading a file from Computer on a online Server

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server

Hey guys I am trying to write a program which can upload files from my computer to a online server..  I have started with a socket programming client side.....
I have written a code which successfully makes a connection to a server and i can send a message to a server also and can get a reply from it...
Have a look..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<strings.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
       char *message , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");


    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.217.24.238");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);
    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");
     //Send some data
    message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Data Send\n");


     //Receive a reply from the server
    if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

    puts("Reply received\n");
    //Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);
    return 0;
}
```

Please suggest me how can i modify this to upload a file from my computer to a server whose IP address and port number is known to me.....
PS: I am new to socket programming ....
Please help....

**Actual**:code which successfully makes a connection to a server and i can send a message to a server also and can get a reply from it...
**Expected:** Modify to upload some file on server whose ip address and port number is known...

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a bit more from HTTP RFC about posting data to the server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

You can get the correct example to learn how to POST the content as the body of HTTP request to the server.

Comment: ..hey i am stuck...Any help would be great... I have read about POST commands but not getting much......